# Kernel exploit shellcode

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, kernel, shellcode

I want to write shellcode for kernel mode on 32-bit Linux that will do this:

```
commit_creds (prepare_kernel_cred(0));
```

So I create a file with:

```
xor eax, eax
call 0x1234567
call 0x1234568
ret
```

Where 0x1234567 is the address of prepare_kernel_cred and 0x1234568 is the address of commit_creds, both found from /proc/kallsyms.

I assemble it with nasm -f elf and objdump -d it to get the machine code.

I get something like:

```
31 c0               which is xor eax, eax
e8 7c 67 06 c1      which is call prepare_kernel_cred
e8 7c 65 06 c1      which is call commit_creds
c3                  which is ret
```

This doesn't work. However, using `e8 79` instead of `e8 7c` and `e8 74` instead of the second `e8 7c`, works. I don't remember where I got this second machine code from (I had it in a different file), but I'm very curious why this would work and not simply assembling it like that would work.

What type of `CALL` is this? Why doesn't it work to simply assemble the code as it is shown above? My toy exploit works fine against my artificial kernel bug if I use the `e8 79` and `e8 74` for the CALLs, but fails when I use the assembled machine code from nasm/objdump.

Answer (score 1):

The CALL variants beginning with E8h are near calls to an address specified by a displacement relative to the current instruction.  This explains why the values need to be different for different instructions.  I'm  at a loss for how you got nasm to emit that code, though.  Are you sure this isn't homework?

Comment: Thanks. No, this is not homework. I'm just trying to make my own toy exploit work against my own kernel (null pointer dereferencing). If I assemble "call 0xc1066480" and "call 0xc1066380" I get e8 7c on both of them. (nasm -f elf, objdump -d on the .o file).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had used the following command to compile this before:

```
gcc -m32 -Ttext=0 -nostdlib
```

This gives me the same result as I had from before. I also get a warning that it defaults to starting from 0x0.

However why doesn't nasm reproduce this? I checked with objdump and the starting address seems to be 0x0 in both files.